# To find subbasis for a topology on X.

Tags: general-topology

Consider the discrete topology $\tau$ on $X:= \{ a,b,c, d,e \}$. Find subbasis for $\tau$ which does not contain any singleton sets.

The definition of subbasis is as follows:

> **Definition:** A *subbasis* $S$ for a topology on $X$ is a collection of subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$.

So let $S$ be equal to the  collection of $\{a,b\}$, $\{c,d\}$ and  $\{d,e\}$.

Clearly union of these three elements is $X$.

So should be $S$ - as defined - be taken as subbasis? Please check the answer I posted in comment.

Comment: $S$ will generate *some topology* on $X$, but will it generate the *desired topology* $T$ on $X$?

Comment: What about the singleton $\{b\}$? Your $S$ doesn't generate it.

Comment: You need that your sub-basis generates, by intersection, all the singletons of $X$

Comment: Can I take S= collection of {a,b} , {b,c} , {c,d} , {d,e} , {a,e} as sub basis?

Comment: One problem that may hinder your progress is that the "definition" you give of subbasis is not complete.  $S$ is a subbasis of $\tau$ if $\{B \mid B \text{ is the intersection of finitely many elements of } S\}$ is a basis for $\tau$.  It follows that the union of all the elements of a subbasis is $X$, but the latter alone is not enough.  Clearly all the singletons give you a basis for $\tau$. Hence...

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** You can write $\{a\}$ as $\{a,b\}\cap\{a,c\}$. Do the same with each of the elements of $X$.

Comment: Can I take S= collection of {a,b} , {b,c} , {c,d} , {d,e} , {a,e} as sub basis?

Comment: @Kavita: Looks good because you can get each point as an open set, so everything is open and the topology generated is indeed discrete.

Answer (score 0):

The collection consisting of all $27$ non-singleton sets is a subbase: each of them is an open set (since the topology is discrete), and every singleton set can be expressed as the intersection of two non-singleton sets.

More economically, the five $4$-element sets constitute a subbase for the discrete topology; each singleton set is the intersection of the four $4$-element sets containing it.

Or just take the **four sets** $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,4,5\}$, $\{2,4\}$, $\{3,5\}$. Note that
$\{1\}=\{1,2,3\}\cap\{1,4,5\}$,
$\{2\}=\{1,2,3\}\cap\{2,4\}$,
$\{3\}=\{1,2,3\}\cap\{3,5\}$,
$\{4\}=\{1,4,5\}\cap\{2,4\}$,
$\{5\}=\{1,4,5\}\cap\{3,5\}$.

Answer (score -1):

The correct singleton sets should be $\{(a,b),(b,c),(c,d),(d,e),(a,e)\}$

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! Please typeset in MathJax. You can find a tutorial here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference